# How to create a Windows service for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, service

In Windows it is possible to create an application that can be installed as a service. This type of application is called a Windows Service. What would be the equivalent of services on Mac OS X? How are they implemented and where to start to learn about it?

I would like to create a service to execute a task automatically, and starting and stopping it on demand.

Comment: Mac at one point was running a modified bsd kernel.  Do they have a cron-like tool you could use?
http://benr75.com/pages/using_crontab_mac_os_x_unix_linux

Comment: You can indeed use `cron` but its use is deprecated in favour of `launchd`.

Comment: ok, I have read launchd and seems to be the right solution. thx

Comment: @willyMon can you please guide me on service, my requirement also likes you reuirement please tell me how to do task automatically like windows services.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to become friends with [`launchd`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/launchd.8.html). You need to create `launchd` configuration files that are placed in one of five locations:

- `~/Library/LaunchAgents`: Per-user agents provided by the user.
- `/Library/LaunchAgents`: Per-user agents provided by the administrator.
- `/Library/LaunchDaemons`: System-wide daemons provided by the
  administrator.
- `/System/Library/LaunchAgents`: Per-user agents provided by Mac OS X.
- `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons`: System-wide daemons provided by Mac OS
  X.

A ***daemon*** is a system-wide service of which there is one instance for all clients. An ***agent*** is a service that runs on a per-user basis.

[Configuration files](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/5/launchd.plist) are in the form of a [property list.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man5/plist.5.html)

The syntax is simple but it's easy to get it wrong. The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd) has a good summary of the options if the [man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/5/launchd.plist) is not to your liking.

Essentially, what you do is install your actual command-line tool (your service) somewhere and then create a `launchd` configuration plist and place it in one of the above locations. You can configure the plist so that `launchd` runs your service at launch or periodically, or in response to various actions (such as the contents of a folder changing).

There is a good in-depth article [here](http://www.afp548.com/article.php?story=20050620071558293).

Comment: The items in /Library (as opposed to a single user's ~/Library) will run for every user who logs in, correct?

Comment: Is there a way to have this app run as root on startup using launchd?

Comment: Yes. You need to use the `/Library/LaunchDaemons` location for your configuration file.

Answer (score 4):

You should take a look at **launchd**, you can do a lot of nifty stuff with it.
For instance, steam has told launchd that whenever steam is deleted, run steam_delete helper tool. This helper tool helps you in uninstalling steam completely from your system.

Others include the auto update mechanism of google chrome on OS X.

A link to help you get started: [Devdaily launchd examples](http://www.devdaily.com/mac-os-x/launchd-examples-launchd-plist-file-examples-mac)