# Application on Startup Mac

Tags: cocoa, launchd

I need to run my application on startup. So when the user boot up his Mac and is about to see his desktop, my application needs to launch. I set my app to run as launchd. I am using the QueuedDirectories flag in the plist of the launchd process. So if I place a file it launches up automatically. I have looked at the question - [How do I launch an application on system startup? (Mac OSX, Cocoa)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205967/how-do-i-launch-an-application-on-system-startup-mac-osx-cocoa). The suggested answer is to use launchd.

I have two questions -

1. In Macs where more than one accounts are present, the application does not launch for the other user(who has not installed it). In Windows you can install program for everyone. Is a similar thing possible on Mac. If so, I can use the Queued directory approach with launchd.
2. Is launchd the right way to start an application at startup/login in Lion as well. Or has Apple added any new feature with Lion which will allow this to be done in a smarter way. I looked up and everything does seem to point towards launchd.

I am targeting Snow leopard and Lion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should be using launchd. Have a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8190180/50122) to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189883/how-to-create-a-windows-service-for-mac-os-x)

Basically, you need to install your launchd configuration file in the root `/Library/LaunchAgents/` folder rather than an individual user's `~/Library/LaunchAgents/` folder. That way, it will launch an instance for each user that logs in.